# Informatica Cloud with Linux VM

Tags: cloud

I am using a variable inside my a mapping to derive a value which is used in the post sesssion command of the same mapping task. when I try to use the variable in the post session command , I am getting old values. Is there any way I can automatically reset after/before every extraction ?

Comment: You should provide your code attempts

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.